# How to query a column with month name using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a query to get the data between `January` to `March` but my problem is that the data is stored using the name of the month (e.g. January, February, etc.) instead of the exact date with timestamp data type. Please see my code below.

**EmployeeController**

```
$from = 'January';
$to = 'March';


$employees = Employee::whereBetween(
           'month',
           [Carbon::parse($from)->month, Carbon::parse($to)->month]
)->get();
```

The result is empty array.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the database to do a `BETWEEN` on 2 strings (e.g. "January" and "March" - as far is it's concerned, that's no different to saying select everything between "Kipper" and "Pluto" - it just doesn't make sense) - you'll probably need to fetch everything then filter in the application.

Comment: @CD001 Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Obviously, nothing is Automatically aware that February comes between January and March, so you are going to have to build a query differently, maybe try a `WHERE month IN('January', 'February', 'March')` but you will of course have to write some code to generate the 3 month names, but that should not be difficult

Comment: Don't forget that you might need to qualify with the year.  Might work ok now, but then next March return January to March 23 plus January to March 22